# Flutter google_nav_bar gets disposed before it should

Tags: flutter

I have a google_nav_bar which gets added to a Scaffold in every Widget in the list head. The app starts and it works as intended, but the app crashes if I switch to Emptyheader or Selectorheader. My guess is that the nav gets disposed after I switch the site, so it needs to be passed in as a reference. Error: `FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): _GNavState#3f071(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)`

EDIT: The problem is the duration of GNav. I think the problem is that the gnav updates the state each ms, and the page updates and unmounts the page when the last ms is reached, but it is already unmounted so it causes the error. Is there a way to intercept the animation when the object is unmounted?

```
Widget heady = SafeArea(
      child: GNav(
          haptic: true,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          gap: 8,
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 12, bottom: 5),
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTabChange: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          tabs: _buttons),
    );
    List<Widget> head = [
      SearchHeader(bottom: heady, body: const HomePage()),
      SearchHeader(bottom: heady, body: const SearchPage()),
      SelectorHeader(
        bottom: heady,
        body: const LibraryPage(),
        tabs: const TabBar(tabs: [Text("Continue"), Text("Favourite"), Text("My")]),
        length: 3,
      ),
      EmptyHeader(bottom: heady, body: const SettingsPage()),
    ];
    return head[_selectedIndex];
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a very similar error @frederik.  Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your `setState` function like this:

```
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}
```

Might need to use `this.mounted`

Comment: doesnt work. Same error